# Experimental examples of how to realize POVM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin

Say I have a spin qubit that is one of two states $\vert\psi_1\rangle$ or $\vert\psi_2\rangle$ and $\langle \psi_2 \vert \psi_1 \rangle \neq 0$. To perform an unambiguous state discrimination, we require a POVM with the following elements:

\begin{align}
\pi_1 & \sim \vert\psi_1^{\perp}\rangle\langle\psi_1^{\perp}\vert \\
\pi_2 & \sim \vert\psi_2^{\perp}\rangle\langle\psi_2^{\perp}\vert \\
\pi_3 & = 1 - \pi_1 - \pi_2
\end{align}

What does this look like in an experiment where I have Stern Gerlach type apparatuses? I'm having trouble understanding how I would actually do this in a lab. My knowledge so far of how to translate measurements from paper to lab apparatuses is restricted to knowing how to measure spin along a given axis and obtain two possible results.

Comment: You cant with just using stern gerlach type apparatuses. If your POVM is not a von Neumann measurement, then you need an ancilla state, a unitary transformation which operates on both qubit (your state + ancilla) and then a von Neumann measurement on both.

Comment: I see. And is there also not an equivalent way of seeing this as randomly selecting from a set of von Neumann measurements and of course, there is some probability assigned to which von Neumann measurement we pick?

Comment: I dont think so. While every such measurement in your comment is represented by a povm, I doubt that every povm can be reperesented in such a way (thats why I think introductory texts using this approach are misleading). Anyway, on this I donr know.a proof so am not 100% sure.